# How to implement Dynamic pivot in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following CTE as my result:

```
formatted as (
SELECT 
    trunc_month,
    section_name,
    total_distinct_users from inter
)
```

﻿I want to pivot the values of month in a dynamic way such that values of month appear as columns. I want this to by done in a dynamic way since I can not provide all past/﻿future values of month. Please note, the format of values in trunc_month is like 2023-11-01.

What I tried to do was execute the following code directly beneath the aforementioned CTE,

```
DECLARE sql_query STRING;

-- Construct the dynamic SQL query
SET sql_query = (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(
      'SELECT section_name, ',
      STRING_AGG(
        'MAX(IF(trunc_month = "' || trunc_month || '", total_distinct_users, NULL)) AS ' || trunc_month
      )
    )
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', trunc_month) AS trunc_month FROM formatted
  )
);

-- Append the FROM clause to the dynamic SQL query
SET sql_query = CONCAT(sql_query, ' FROM formatted GROUP BY section_name');

-- Execute the dynamic SQL query
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_query;
```

But it gives me an error:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected keyword DECLARE at [322:1]
```